# About a positive definite matrix composed of functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices

If $A_{N \times N} (x)$ is complex $N \times N$ positive definite matrix whose components $a_{ij}(x)$ are $C^\infty$ functions, then can we say that the positive definite matrix $A^{-1}$ (the inverse of $A$) is also consists of $C^\infty$ functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula $A^{-1}=\frac 1{\det A}(A^*)^t$, where $A^*_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}\Delta_{ij},$ and $\Delta_{ij}$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$ without the row $i$ and column $j$. The map $x\mapsto \delta A(x)$ is $C^{\infty}$ as a finite sum of product of such functions. As it never vanishes, $x\mapsto  \frac 1{\det A(x)}$ is smooth too. As $x\mapsto \Delta_{i,j}(x)$ is smooth, we are done.